# Is there a way to set an Icon URL in FCM?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to deliver push notifications for my social media app.

I would like to change the icon (my app logo) with a user profile photo for example like in TikTok or iMessage.

I can't find anywhere to change this `icon` parameter in the admin SDK (i am sending push notifications from my server in python).

Is there even a way to change it with FCM ?

On Android, the parameter exist inside the `AndroidNotification` class :

```
notification=messaging.AndroidNotification(
                body="Notification android",
                title="hey",
                image="https://example.com/anypostedcontent.png",
                sound="default",
                priority="high",
                icon="https://example.com/anyimage.png"
            ),
```

But seems to have no effect.